# Emberjs update a value in a promise

Tags: ember.js

I think this is a very straight forward question, but I don't know how to do it properly.

In my app I get a promise from indexedDB with all my data, but when I receive it, I need to update a field inside this one.

e.g :

The object I get back is (at a very basic state) :

```
{
    title: 'hello',
    description: 'this is my description',
    images: ''
}
```

I would like to modify the images field with an image that I fetch somewhere else. How can I do that with a promise because it is nested inside a lot of field, like content->content->0->_data->MyObject

Thanks for the help !

[EDIT] Ideally I would also be able to parse the promise data, like making a forEach and if I find a specific key inside my promise data I do something.